# Pandas: Add Argument to Apply with Multiple Inputs

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use apply with two columns and add additional arguments. My use case is to perform a search on a column and return the regex to another column without overwriting existing values in the other column. Maybe iterrows is a better option :).

```
import random
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

    #create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({ 

    'a':np.random.choice( ['the_panda','it_python','my_shark'], 6),        
    })
df["b"] = ""
```

Yields:

```
    a   b
0   the_panda   
1   my_shark    
2   my_shark    
3   the_panda   
4   it_python   
5   the_panda
```

Each time I apply my function if the value appears in column "a" then I want to write the search string to column "b". So if I used "panda" and then "shark" to search it would look like this:

```
a   b
0   the_panda   panda
1   my_shark    shark
2   my_shark    shark
3   the_panda   panda
4   it_python   
5   the_panda   panda
```

I created a simple function:

```
def search_log(b,a,search_sting):
    so = re.search(search_string,a)
    if so:
        return search_string
    else:
        return b
```

However I'm not sure if there is a way to add additional arguments to the apply function in this case? Here is what I'm trying:

```
search_string = 'panda'
df['b'] = df.apply(lambda x: search_log(x['b'],x['a']),args=(search_string,),axis=1)
```

Which yields:

```
TypeError: ('<lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given', 'occurred at index 0')
```

...or

```
df['b'] = df.apply(lambda x: search_log(x['b'],x['a'],args=(search_string,),axis=1))
```

which yields:

```
KeyError: ('b', 'occurred at index a')
```

Comment: yes, that is because of random.choice

Comment: It looks that way because of the way the dataframes appear when I copy them onto SO. I've updated my example to hopefully make that more clear.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstand your problem, don't you want simply to do: `df['b'] = df.apply(lambda x: search_log(x['b'],x['a'],search_string),axis=1)`?

Comment: Wow, Ben. that's it exactly. I got so caught up with using the "args" parameter. Thanks!

Comment: actually, it's bit tricky because if you do `search_string ='python'` and `df['b'] = df.apply(lambda x: search_log(x['b'],x['a'],'shark'),axis=1)`, the answer is interesting! So I see why you where looking for "args".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = ["panda","shark","python"]
df["b"] = df["a"].apply(lambda y:[x for x in string if x in y][0] if len([x for x in string if x in y])==1 else "")
```

Output:

```
           a b
0  it_python  
1   my_shark  
2   my_shark  
3  the_panda  
4   my_shark  
5   my_shark  

       a       b
0  it_python  python
1   my_shark   shark
2   my_shark   shark
3  the_panda   panda
4   my_shark   shark
5   my_shark   shark
```